# Why don't Wifi router UI's use confirmation password boxes?

Tags: material-design, password, confirmation, password-change

Consider the scenario of trying to update the Wifi password for a router. Pulling up two sources I have access to, both [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/_detail/media/doc/walkthrough-wifi-1-7.png?id=docs%3Aguide-quick-start%3Awalkthrough_wifi) and Google's Home/Wifi app only have a single input box for changing the password.

**OpenWRT**:

[image: OpenWRT]

**Google**:

[image: Google]

Password input usually comes with a type twice style system (or even a type thrice system for `Current`, `New`, `Confirm`).

[image]

Why do these two examples seem to break from the normal routine of password changing UX?

Does changing a Wifi password need a type twice system? General answers to this second question are valuable, but a focus on Material Design practices would be optimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mistyping an intended wifi password is quick and easy to fix.** As soon as you set the password, your next step is to join the network with the password. You essentially know right away if there was a mistake, likely with your router settings screen still up, and you fix it.

Contrast that with a traditional account password setup - your next step might not be a login. You might not try entering the password again for days or even weeks, and when you can't successfully login, it's a bit of a frustrating experience to reset the password and get back into the account. The confirmation step helps catch unintended typos before you need to use the password.